# How to import .jar with .dll to Android

Tags: android, dll, jar

I'm working on an Android app (Android Studio 2.2) which uses a library:
http://sgjp.pl/morfeusz/download/20161113/jmorfeusz-0.1.0-Windows-i386.tar.gz
On their site: 
http://sgjp.pl/morfeusz/dopobrania.html.po (caution: Polish language)
they say its for Windows 32. In the download link there are one .jar and one .dll files.
How can I import all of it to my Android project to check if it'll be working?

Comment: Android does not use DLL files. Windows does.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use this in Android?

Comment: Ask the author if the author has created a port to Android.

Comment: There is C++ version of this library. There is also 'Include C++ support' in Android Studio. What do you think about that?

Comment: I think that somebody with sufficient time and skill might be able to get it working. I have no idea what this library does, let alone what its C++ code does, to know whether it is something that can readily be ported to Android or not.